# Does DetachedCriteria/ICriteria have any restriction on join depth?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, icriteria, nhibernate-criteria

Imagine I have `C1`, `C2` and `C3` classes. Suppose we can have `string dummy = c1.ContainerC2.ContainerC3.Prop1`. Is there any restriction that does not allow me to create an alias directly from `C3` without having other classes in the criteria? For example:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<T>("root");
criteria.CreateAlias("ContainerC2.ContainerC3", "alias_abcdef");
```

I have problems with it. It generates SQL query that has following error message:

The multi-part identifier "alias_cont1_.HotelName" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go to the ContainerC2 directly with CriteriaAPI. Instead you should do the folloing:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<T>("root");
criteria.CreateCreteria("ContainerC2")
        .CreateAlias("ContainderC3", "alias_abcdef");
```

Comment: Criteria API works in this way. If you want to move to some property you need to create a new criteria for it.

Comment: Dummy API, do they make some improvement in NH 3 ?

Comment: Improvement is QueryOver API. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx. But I think it is the same idea in your case